# R, how to use strptime on Linux with timezone and with junk Unicode character

Tags: linux, r, strptime, sanitization

When I see the posting date from the web, I don't see

> `<U+200E>`

before date, but after I scraped the web, I see "< U+200E>" before the date somehow. So I saved it as csv file somewhere and read it in.

```
library(XML)
gethelp.url = 'http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Get-Help-with-Fusion-360/bd-p/123'
gethelp.df =htmlTreeParse(gethelp.url, useInternalNodes = T)
getdate <- xpathSApply(gethelp.df, "//span[@class='local-date']", xmlValue)
postingdate <- as.data.frame(getdate)
write.csv(postingdate,"postingdate.csv")
postingdate <- read.csv("postingdate.csv")

head(postingdate)
  X            getdate
1 1 <U+200E>07-21-2013
2 2 <U+200E>01-23-2014
3 3 <U+200E>03-08-2014
4 4 <U+200E>01-23-2014
5 5 <U+200E>04-29-2014
6 6 <U+200E>04-29-2014
```

I wanted to calculate the difference in days between these date and today, So I removed the < U+200E> using gsub.

```
postingdate$date3<- gsub(pattern="200",replacement="", postingdate$getdate)
postingdate$date3<- gsub(pattern="E>",replacement="", postingdate$date3)
postingdate$date3<- gsub(pattern="<U",replacement="", postingdate$date3)
postingdate$date3<- gsub(pattern="\\+",replacement="", postingdate$date3)
```

If I just use difftime like below,

```
postingdate$diff <- difftime(Sys.Date(),postingdate$date,units="days")
```

it throws out an error message.

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
In addition: Warning message:
In `$.data.frame`(postingdate, date) : Name partially matched in data frame
```

but if I use strptime, it works on window but it gives NA on Linux

```
postingdate$date <- strptime(postingdate$date3,format="%m-%d-%Y")
postingdate$diff <- difftime(Sys.Date(),postingdate$date,units="days")
```

After extensive googling, it seems like there's no difference in strptime usage on either platform. Any advice I can get this strptime running on Linux?

Comment: This is partially a question about removing Unicode junk (http://www.charbase.com/200e-unicode-left-to-right-mark), and partially about strftime.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

```
strptime("07-21-2013",format="%m-%d-%Y")
```

returns

```
[1] "2013-07-21 EDT"
```

so the timezone is messing up difftime. Instead use

```
format(postingdate$date3,format="%m-%d-%Y", usetz=FALSE)
```

also

```
gsub(pattern="<U\\+200E>",replacement="", postingdate$getdate)
```

is a more compact regular expression to remove the part you don't want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The regular expression is much more compact! I haven't these tested out timezone code on Linux but on window "format(postingdate$date3,format="%m-%d-%Y", usetz=FALSE)" throws out an error message when I use it with difftime.